# ValueError when working with hidden_markov in python

Tags: python, hidden-markov-models, valueerror

I'm getting the following error when I run the `train.hmm()`

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (7,20) (1,7)
```

I know what a broadcast error is and went through the docs. But I cannot change dimensions of the matrix as it will pop an error in another place. The code is as given below.

```
start_probability = np.matrix( '0.5 0.02 0.18 0.05 0.01 0.2 0.04 ')
transition_probability = np.matrix('0.9 0.012 0.012 0.012 0.002 0.05 0.012 \
;  0.03 0.35 0.05 0.05 0.02 0.45 0.05 \
;  0.03 0.05 0.45 0.05 0.02 0.35 0.05 \
;  0.1 0.1 0.1 0.4 0.1 0.1 0.1 \
;  0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.4 0.1 0.1 \
;  0.2 0.05 0.05 0.05 0.05 0.4 0.2 \
;  0.12 0.12 0.12 0.12 0.01 0.12 0.39')
emission_probability = np.matrix(np.ones((7, 20)) * 0.05)

test = hmm(states,possible_observation,start_probability,transition_probability,emission_probability)
observations = ['A', 'S','T','A']
obs4 = ['C', 'A','G']
observation_tuple = []
observation_tuple.extend( [observations,obs4] )
quantities_observations = [10, 20]
num_iter=1000
e,t,s = test.train_hmm(observation_tuple,num_iter,quantities_observations)
```

The error corresponds to the last line. If I transpose the `start_prbability` or `emission_probability` matrix, I'll get an error in the `test = hmm()` line itself.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

Change line 349 of `hmm_class.py` to,

```
emProbNew = emProbNew/ np.reshape(em_norm.transpose(),[-1,1])
```

Not the best solution I know, but I think the author overlooked the fact that `Python` would not always be able to know what he meant here with division.

Comment: Try to format your code either using 4 spaces or the code button which looks like {} in order to make your answers more readable.

Comment: Doesn't that mean there's a mistake in the library? Why should I meddle with the code from given library?